# How to allow function reordering in FileCheck test?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I'd like to write a LIT test for an LLVM pass which can reorder function definitions in the IR. I would like to make assertions about the contents of several functions that are reordered.

```
; (a) need to match "define internal void @foo()"
; (b) need to match "call void @bar()"
define internal void @foo() {
    call void @bar()
    ret void
}

; (c) need to match "define internal void @bar()"
; (d) need to match "call void @baz()"
define internal void @bar() {
    call void @baz()
    ret void
}

; (e) need to match "define internal void @baz()"
define internal void @baz() {
    ret void
}
```

The dependency graph I would like to implement is this:

```
a  c  e
|  |
b  d
```

Comment: This sounds like an [xy question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/fnord), perhaps you could rephrase or elaborate?

Comment: You're right. I would still like to ask the more general question of arbitrary DAGs, but I'm still new to FileCheck so hopefully learning to use it a bit better will help me to ask that question more clearly. I've edited the question to ask about my specific situation.

Comment: Is `CHECK-DAG` useful maybe?

Comment: That's a very much better question now. Couldn't really make head or tails of it before. Some similar problems have been solved by shaping the test such that the result order can be inferred, ie. even if the order isn't easily predictable in the general case, you've chosen the test case such that it can be predicted. (Note that in many cases, having a stable order is desirable even if the order isn't meaningful, because if the order is stable, you can diff today's IR against last week's IR and get only the substantive changes. Nice for debugging.)

Comment: The ordering _is_ stable, so I ended up just making the assertions in the resulting order. I'd still like an answer to the question that I asked, though, so I'll leave the question open.